# adverb "synonym" for "whatever" — it doesn't matter, unrestricted

Tags: single-word-requests, adverbs

> It's possible to chain identical modules to operate on ________ly large inputs.

I want a word that means, the size of the input doesn't matter, it can be any size, it is unrestricted/unbounded/has no upper limit.

"Trivially", "unlimitedly", "ambiguously" have entered by head but are not what I am looking for (and "ambiguously" doesn't even make sense).

---

> It's possible to chain identical modules to operate on however-large inputs.

> It's possible to chain identical modules to operate on whatever inputs.

Have the right kind of sentiment, but I feel like there's an idiomatic word ending in -ly that fits better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest *arbitrarily*. The word is often used in science when discussing a non-specific quantity that may be of any chosen or otherwise determined (perhaps random, or merely exemplary) value.

There is a useful discussion at

> https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/775333/arbitrarys-meaning

Answer (score 0):

An adverb which is commonly used for this (especially in technical contexts as suggested by your example sentence) is ***indefinitely***.

> It's possible to chain identical modules to operate on ***indefinitely***
> large inputs.

Lexico:

> ***[indefinitely](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/indefinitely)***
> *ADVERB*
> **1.1** (as submodifier) To an unlimited or unspecified degree or extent.
> ‘an indefinitely large number of channels’